# asp.net relative path IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl

Tags: asp.net, iis, relative-path

I am running into some issues with relative paths when deploying my website. This is an ASP.Net **webform** project
The site running without issues on the local machine, with links pointing as they should.

I deployed the site to subfolder (not the IIS root) and made that folder an application. currently my site is deployed to http://www.example.com/foo/
The first issue i noted was that links like `/Account/Register.aspx` would on my local machine point to `https://localhost:44337/Account/Register` but on the deployed site it would point to `http://www.example.com/Account/Register.aspx` instead of the correct path `http://www.example.com/foo/Account/Register.aspx`.
That was relatively easily fixable by changing the links from `/Account/Register.aspx` to `~/Account/Register.aspx`.
A more difficult issue was dealing with an email confirmation link generated through the code below:

```
string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
```

On my local machine, the link points (correctly).

```
https://localhost:44337:80/Account/Confirm?code=blablabla
```

On the web deployed app, the link points to

```
http://www.example.com:80/Account/Confirm?code=blablabla
```

Physical path

```
E:\web\mysite\htdocs\Account\Confirm
```

The correct one should have been

```
http://www.example.com:80/foo/Account/Confirm?code=blablabla
```

Could anyone please suggest how to deal with this problem with relative links overall or specifically how to get IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl to generate the link with the right relative path?
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply to adjust the url path in GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl in identitymodules.cs